# Access to the values in a multi-level JSON-structure

Tags: java, json, json-simple

There is my JSON-structure:

```
{
   "date":"19.11.2013",
   "parent":{
      "child1":[
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"10:30",
         },
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"12:20",
         }
      ],
      "child2":[
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"10:30",
         },
         {
            "date":"2013-11-19",
            "time":"12:20",
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

And it's my code at the moment:

```
public class json {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

        URL urlData = new URL("http://path.to/json");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlData.openConnection().getInputStream(), "utf-8"));
        String struct = reader.readLine();

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(struct);
        JSONObject lev1 = (JSONObject) obj;
        System.out.println(lev1.get("date"));
    }
}
```

I got a *date* value (*19.11.2013*), but I don't know how to get child's values of *date* and *time*.
I'm using json-simple library.

Comment: What did you try up till now? Do you have any code?

Comment: According to http://jsonlint.com/ the posted JSON is not valid. Maybe you want to fix that first (or possible copy/paste errors here).

Comment: It is always easier and recommended to parse JSON in clientside

Comment: @MarkKorzhov and your json having error 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the idea :

```
JSONObject parent = (JSONObject) lev1.get("parent");
JSONArray child1 = (JSONArray) parent.get("child1"); // same for child2
for (Object elem : child1) {
    System.out.prinlnt("date =  " + ((JSONObject) elem).get("date"));
    System.out.prinlnt("time =  " + ((JSONObject) elem).get("time"));
}
```

Let me know if it does not compile, otherwise should work.

Answer (score 1):

Since, the names of the array are `child1` and `child2` (which means the names are different), inside the parent object , first you have to fetch these names, and then for each array, fetch date and time.

Here `struct` , is the jsonString:

```
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Object obj = parser.parse(struct);
        JSONObject lev1 = (JSONObject) obj;
        Object jObj = lev1.get("parent");
        List keys = new ArrayList();
        if (jObj instanceof Map) {
            Map map = (Map) jObj;
            Set keySet = map.keySet();
            for (Object s : keySet) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jObj;
                JSONArray jarr = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get(s.toString());
                for (int i = 0; i < jarr.size(); i++) {
                    Object get = jarr.get(i);
                    JSONObject job = (JSONObject) get;
                    String date = job.get("date").toString();
                    String time = job.get("time").toString();
                    System.out.println("Date: " + date + " , Time: " + time);
                }
            }
        }
```